# What makes the function call?

Tags: ruby

I was trying to learn `yield` method which was very confusing to me. Finally when I thought I have understood the method ,suddenly this code appears

```
def test
   puts "You are in the method"
   yield
   puts "You are again back to the method"
   yield
end
```

when I execute a file containing this code, it doesn't print anything. It's understood that no one is calling this method so no output.

But in the same file if I add

```
test {puts "You are in the block"}
```

below the test function suddenly it start printing the puts statements.

I don't understand who is calling the method. If `test {..}` block is causing the call shouldn't it execute its content first?

But the ouput is

```
You are in the method
You are in the block
You are again back to the method
You are in the block
```

Comment: `test {puts "You are in the block"} ` cause the call. block is not executed but passed to the `test` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you wrote `test { puts "You are in the block"}`, that *was* you calling the function. You were calling `test`, and passing one argument, a block.

Each method can take one block argument implicitly. When you call `yield` inside a function, that's you saying "Invoke the block argument." So when you called `yield` twice, you invoked the block argument twice, in between other `puts` statements.

Answer (score 2):

> when I execute a file containing this code, it doesn't print anything.
>   It's understood that no one is calling this method so no output.

Defining a method has nothing to do with calling it. You can define hundreds of methods each of which outputs something, but running the file will result in no output, since any method was actually called.

> But in the same file if I add `test {puts "You are in the block"}`
>   below the test function suddenly it start printing the puts statements.

Correct, you are ***actually calling*** a method passing a block to it.

> What makes the function call?

Typing a method's name passing arguments to it (if it accepts any (block can be passed to any method despite its arity)) calls it.